# Replace "UpdateTargetId" with "LoadingElementId" while loading?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

So currently, I am trying to replace the partial view that is refresh with ajax. I am trying to replace it with the loader

The image below should explain what I am trying to do.
[image]

When the button is clicked, it should render the loader (blue rectangle) in place of the partial view (red rectangle and the text right above it, i forgot to put the text in there too) but, as you can see- it renders them separately.

Here is how the button is being called:

```
 @{using (Ajax.BeginForm("_LogOut", "User",
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = "userInformation",
                    LoadingElementId = "loader-container",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "GET"
                }))
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-raised text-center">
                    <i class="material-icons">refresh</i> 
                    Refresh Data
                </button>
            }
        }
```

If you want a more indepth look of how this partial view is built: http://pastebin.com/1mMfpQyB

The button refreshes the data properly- so it works! The only issue is the (what I assume to be) "UpdateTargetId" and "LoadingElementId" interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the actual best solution, but it works- albeit a bit hacky:

```
            @{
            using (Ajax.BeginForm("_LogOut", "User",
                new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = "userInformation",
                    LoadingElementId = "loadercontainer",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    OnBegin = "$('#userInformation').slideUp(); $('#loadercontainer').slideDown()",
                    OnComplete = "$('#userInformation').slideDown(); $('#loadercontainer').slideUp()"
                }))
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-raised text-center">
                    <i class="material-icons">refresh</i> 
                    Refresh Data
                </button>
            }
        }
```

To summarize, I delegated the ajaxoptions onbegin and oncomplete to call some jquery:

```
OnBegin = "$('#userInformation').slideUp(); $('#loadercontainer').slideDown()",
OnComplete = "$('#userInformation').slideDown(); $('#loadercontainer').slideUp()"
```